# Rails project using BDD(RSpec and Cucumber)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bdd, rspec-rails

Basically I want to use BDD(RSpec and cucumber) to make a complete rails project.Is it possible and if yes is it good to make a project using outside-in Rails development? 
I will be doing it the way as it is given in - The RSpec Book .
Thanks in advance .

I want to make a rails project. I am thinking of making it using Rspec and Cucumber.
What I mean is using TDD. Writing tests and then passing it by writing the desired application code .

Comment: Please be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so.

You can use rspec for any ruby code: rails, sinatra, writing a gem and even plain ruby code. But you can use this if you want to work on rails https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

I'm not very familiar with cucumber, but if you visit its wiki https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki , you'll find that it can be used in rails, sinatra, Merb, even with other language